# Saving primitive data on android device

Tags: android, file, save

I am creating a game, and need to store the users current level in a file, and then read it next time they are on to serve the correct level data.

It would be as simple as saving a variable called currentLevel into this file.

How may I do so? I have attempted using Shared Preferences, but that data is lost when i kill the task.

Comment: `SharedPreferences` provide persistent storage. Are you sure that you're saving the variable correctly?

Comment: I have pasted the code here. pastebin.com/AN5Rxtp0

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is SharedPreferences. Writing to shared preferences is the same as writing to a file but simpler! data will be persistent and it only gets deleted when user goes to setting->apps and choses clear data for your app or when user uninstalls the app.

If your data is getting lost you're probably doing something wrong. put your code here so we can take a look at it.